# get_post_type_archive_link('post') returns current category archive

Tags: posts, categories, archives

I am using `get_post_type_archive_link('post')` on my `index.php` page to get the url of all posts from all categories.

I'm using it in a filter. I have listed all the categories separately using

```
$filter_cat=array();
$categories = get_categories();
foreach ($categories as $category_one) {
    $cat_ID = $category_one->cat_ID;
    $cat_name = $category_one->name;
    $filter_cat[] ='<a href="'.get_category_link( $cat_ID ).'" data-cat="'.$cat_ID.'">'.$cat_name.'</a>';
}
$filter_cat_out = '<li class="filter_button_category">' . implode('</li><li class="filter_button_category">', $filter_cat) . '</li>';
$filters_out = '<li class="filter_button_category filter_button_all">
                    <i class="icon-tag"></i><a href="'.get_post_type_archive_link('post').'" class="all_posts">'.esc_attr__('All', 'mytheme').'</a>
                </li>
                '.$filter_cat_out;
```

Now everything works fine, if I use blog as my main page, but if I select some page as a static page, and I get to my index page manually (I need to go to one of the categories), the 'All' link will always point to current category instead of archive page with all the categories listed.

Is such thing even possible? Getting a link to a page where all the categories will be listed in my archive page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`get_post_type_archive_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_archive_link) doesn't return a link for the post type `post`, because technically it has no archive registered on registration of the post type. You can check this, if you inspect the output of `get_post_type_object( 'post' )`. So actually `get_post_type_archive_link( 'post' )` will return `false` - see [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1114).

You can get the link for the page for the posts another way:

```
$permalink = get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) );
```

Comment: Your solution returns the first post link :\ I suspected that something like what you've said could happen, wasn't 100% sure.

Comment: Have you set the blog page via »Dasboard > Settings > Reading > Front page displays > A static page«? @dingo_d Or to say it another way, you have to input a valid ID.

Comment: When I use static page, as I've mentioned in my question, I can't get the link, when I set wp to display my blog posts, it works. But I don't want to display my front page as a blog page. If I understand you correctly, I need to set some page, to be my posts page for your link to work, no?

Comment: Firstly, setting the »Posts page« at above mentioned settings page, doesn't make that page the front page. Those settings are well documented, read up on them to know more. Secondly, you don't need to use - or probably better, set - that, you could work with a page (template), which is likely what you are doing. Last but not least, to get the (correct) permalink you need to input an ID or post object - valid of course - if you do that, then you'll get the link. Otherwise the current post will be returned, which is what happened for you. @dingo_d

Comment: Yep, as I thought, for your solution to work I need to have a page assigned as a blog page. I'll accept it, even tho it's not completely what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: I probably wasn't clear enough, I can set static page to be my front page, in which case I can (but don't have to) set a page to be my default archive page. I can also set my page to list my posts. Don't have to be condescending, I know my way around wordpress ;)

Comment: I have no intention to be condescending, just to be very clear. @dingo_d

Comment: This is no longer true. `get_post_type_archive_link('post')` returns the permalink of the main post page. At least if you have `home.php` in your theme.